# What Open Source Packages are available to provide routing?

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, software-recommendations, routing

I am looking for ways to validate mileage charged by our contractors.  They are paid from a central location to a customer, and then from the customer to a drop off location.

I use QGIS for a bunch of stuff and also have access to MapInfo Pro.

I need to do the following:

> - route individual trips to get total distance in each direction
> - also need to know if parts of one trip overlap the other, and by how much (i.e. km)
> - and if the second trip ends anywhere along the route of the first trip (i.e. they came back the same way they went out)

I have been messing around with PostgreSQL and pgRouting for a couple days and it's pretty confusing to me.

Comment: This question is pretty broad. Could you explain which problems you have with pgRouting?

Comment: Welcome to GIS@Se. You question is very broad. You might do better by asking something like "What Open Source Packages are available to provide routing ..." In this way you are more likely to get answers that may point you to a better solution.

Comment: thanks for the responses.  underdark - I guess I just have trouble with command line applications being spoiled with user interfaces for so long. was trying to use pgRouting for the first time on a mac when I use windows most of the time (blocked from installing on my windows machine at the moment).

Comment: Would you say that you are limiting your search to solutions with a GUI? Try pgRoutingLayer plugin for QGIS. It provides a GUI to query a pgRouting database but you still need to set up the database using SQL before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a GUI for pgRouting, you can install the pgRoutingLayer plugin for QGIS. It provides a GUI to access pgRouting functions to compute routes. The routes can be displayed and exported to QGIS layers which you can manipulate and analyze any way you want. You can see the plugin in action in the following screenshot (panel on the right).

[image]

The plugin requires a configured pgRouting database. When you have access to your Windows machine again, you could look at http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/ for instructions.

Comment: I now have a running version of Postgres with PostGIS and pgRouting.  I am unable to load the Vienna example from your link for some reason.  Have tried my own files but get errors such as "NOTICE:  ERROR: Can not determine the srid of the geometry "the_geom" in table public.Roads2" when trying to build a topology.  The tutorials I have found are great for people that use this a lot, but there still seems to be gaps that I don't understand yet.   I am closer now, but still so far away haha.

Comment: That might be worth a separate question. We need information on the fileformat of your input data and how you imported it. The SRID is stored in the geometry_columns table but it should be populated on data import if you import e.g. a Shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

Our [RW Net 4](http://www.routeware.dk/rwnet4/rwnet.php) library can handle your three needs, from either QGIS (python) or MapInfo, with MapInfo being somewhat easier. But it isn't open source and I hope it isn't confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at all the [OpenStreetMap Routers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) which are available for desktop, mobile or server scenario. But I fear you'll still have to do a bit coding for your requirements.